# GBA reading 16-bit values (or instructions) from 32-bit bus

Tags: memory, game-boy-advance

The GBA has various memory sections (e.g. IWRAM, EWRAM, ROM, etc), each with a bus width of either 16 bits or 32 bits. To my knowledge, the ARM7TDMI lacks any cache. When the CPU fetches 16-bit values from a section with a 32-bit bus (e.g. Thumb instructions from IWRAM), would it fetch from memory twice if it were reading half of a word right after reading the other half?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The GBA has various memory sections (e.g. IWRAM, EWRAM, ROM, etc), each with a bus width of either 16 bits or 32 bits.

Of these only IWRAM (Internal Work RAM) is 32 bit wide. It's located on-chip, tight coupled with the CPUs and able to deliver a word within a single cycle.

> To my knowledge, the ARM7TDMI lacks any cache.

It may be useful to keep in mind that ARM7TDMI is only a logical definition of a core. Its actual interface items, like memory buffers for management of 16/32 bit access, are implementation dependent - even more so when part of an ASIC like with the GBA. Items like

> When the CPU fetches 16-bit values from a section with a 32-bit bus (e.g. Thumb instructions from IWRAM), would it fetch from memory twice if it were reading half of a word right after reading the other half?

This is only marginal part of the CPU, but handled by the memory interface.

More important: **It does not matter**.

The IWRAM, as only 32 bit wide memory,

- is able to deliver a word within a single cycle.
- Any single access will need at least a single cycle.
- Any instruction accessing memory can do so within one cycle.
- Executing two consecutive 16 bit accesses will always take two cycles.
- Any ability to deliver two 16 bit words in one cycle can thus be not used.

Comment: The memory interface of ARM7TDMI core is quite defined: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0210/c/Memory-Interface?lang=en and it does support only 32bit data width, although it requires the memory to be byte-addressable at writes. If GBA supports 32bit reads and writes into 16bit memories it might mean there is some external (to the core) circuitry that changes access width and number.

Comment: @LVD, ofc it does as well support smaller reads using MAS. This is especially relevant when fetching THUMB code, as here each half word is fetched in its own cycle.